# Android Studio 2.3 for mac: gradle sync failed, error in opening zip file

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

This happened after I updated to the 2.3 version. All the projects, including newly-created projects have this issue.
This is part of the log file (not quite sure which part is useful)

```
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:217)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:765)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:749)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:227)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:415)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:494)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:133)
... 4 more
2017-03-22 22:23:04,260 [ 114296]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: error in opening zip file 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: error in opening zip file
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:86)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:361)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:769)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:749)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:227)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:415)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:494)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:133)
... 4 more

 2017-03-22 22:23:04,396 [ 114432]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2017-03-22 22:23:04,396 [ 114432]   INFO - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Cause: error in opening zip file

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2017-03-22 22:23:04,396 [ 114432]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'CourtCounter' failed: Cause: error in opening zip file

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2017-03-22 22:23:04,806 [ 114842]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'CourtCounter' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
 2017-03-22 22:23:05,632 [ 115668]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-22 22:23:05,633 [ 115669]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-22 22:23:05,635 [ 115671]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-22 22:23:05,639 [ 115675]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

I would be really grateful if you can help me out (I'm just a beginner)
And this is my build.gradle file.

```
  buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
     }
      allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
  }
  task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

Comment: Any chance you could post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @AndyLeo add it to your post (edit the post and add it as formatted-code text) not as a comment

Comment: Thank you. I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio **2.3** requires:

- Gradle plugin -at least- version **2.3.0**

in the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
  }
}
```

- And this plugin requires Gradle -at least- version **3.3**

> You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project
>   Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle
>   distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>   file

in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
...
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
...
```

[More details](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

---

After making sure of all of above, if you still have problems in build try to clean `Gradle` cache folder and rebuild:

Open `File` then `Settings` Then `Build, Execution and Deployment` then `Gradle` and search for `Service directory path` this is the Gradle cache folder path.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I checked and there is no problem. 2.3 and 3.3. Also checked these files. Everything seems to be good. But the problem is still there.

Comment: @AndyLeo try to delete contents of gradle cache folder (`C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle` if on windows OR `/home/username/.gradle` if on Linux OR `your other path` if you changed it) and then rebuild

Comment: Strange! I cannot find my .gradle folder (i am on mac) May that be related to the problem?

Comment: @AndyLeo in Android Studio, Open `File` then `Settings` Then `Build, Execution and Deployment` then `Gradle` and search for `Service directory path`  this is the gradle cache path

Comment: @AndyLeo glad i could help :)

Comment: I just delete it, It's working now.

    rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem my solution is a bit rude but it works for me, I delete ~/.gradle and install newly:

```
rm ~ ./gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

I also find this error! luckly I solved it!

it's my solution:(mac OS)

1. open `in the gradle-wrapper.properties file`,and copy the `distributionUrl` URL:

`https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

2. use your browser or downloader to download the `.zip` file (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
   )
3. in Android studio，

open `file-other settings-default settings ,

and then  search `Gradle`,

then copy the value of `Service Directory path`(/Users/hewro/.gradle).

4. open `terminal` :

`cd /Users/hewro/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

`cd gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9`

`cp cp /Users/hewro/Downloads/gradle-3.3-all.zip ./`

5. Restart software

Answer (score 0):

In my mac OS i fixe the error by grant permissions 777 to android folder