# Error in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently downloaded Android Studio 2.3. But I don't know why I have been getting this error. I also reinstalled Android Studio but get the same error.

The error is :

```
Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
```

[This is the screenshot of the error page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n0Dg.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954682/android-studio-2-3-for-mac-gradle-sync-failed-error-in-opening-zip-file/42954852#42954852

Comment: We do not provide *urgent* help here. If you need *urgent* or *immediate* help, hire a contractor and pay them a sufficiently high rate that they will give you their prompt attention.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of internet network. Also, check if all the required packages are installed in Android sdk and gradle is updated.

Comment: alright... so now I have to uninstall Android studio and sdk and then reinstall everything OR should I just update sdk and gradle ... But how and from where can I updates these packages?